# JavaScript: Get value inside Number prototype function

Tags: javascript

I try to use `includes` in prototype but it does not work but I do not get the expected results:

```js
Number.prototype.inList = function (list) {
  return list.includes(this);
}

let value = 0;

let find1 = value.inList([0,1]);
let find2 = [0,1].includes(value);

console.log("find1", find1); // false
console.log("find2", find2); // true
```

Comment: I assume you understand the risks of overriding built in prototypes.?

Comment: I don't override includes, it is a new function inList. I edit my question which could be confusing...

Comment: Your overriding a built in Number.   Have you ever wondered why there is no `Array.contains`?,  A very popular lib called mooTools is to blame for that one, IOW: And the ES spec had to be changed and called it includes instead , all because a popular lib decided to alter Array.prototype with a function it decided to implement in its way.  Not saying you don't do this, but just pointing out the risks of overriding a built-in's prototype, and is the reason most libs avoid doing it.  For example underscore could have implemented it's lib via the prototype, let's say it's a good job they didn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens in non strict mode, where compatibility requires that `this` is always an object, not a primitive. So in your case `this` is an instance of the `Number` constructor, and of course that object does not occur in your list.

In strict mode your code works, as `this` will be the primitive value (number)

```js
Number.prototype.inList = function (list) {
  "use strict";
  return list.includes(this);
}

let value = 0;

let find1 = value.inList([0,1]);
let find2 = [0,1].includes(value);

console.log("find1", find1); // true
console.log("find2", find2); // true
```

Here the strict mode is only effective on the function -- and this is enough for this issue. If your script has no "legacy dependencies", you should better set it globally.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Number#valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/valueOf):

> The valueOf() method returns the wrapped primitive value of a Number object.

```js
Number.prototype.inList = function (list) {
  return list.includes(this.valueOf());
}

let value = 0;
console.log(value.inList([0,1]));
```

Comment: No, don't do that. Prevent it from being wrapped in the first place.

Comment: @Bergi can you explain why it's wrong to do this?

Comment: It's inefficient and only a workaround instead of solving the root issue. Also for the edge case `const n = new Number(); n.inList([n])` I would expect `true`.